# Mapping native query to JPQL (With extra join condition >> ON ... AND ...)

Tags: jpa, jpql

**JPA Entities**

**Organization entity**

```
@Entity
public class Organization implements Serializable{
    private Integer id; // @Id
    private String name;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

**Place entity**

```
@Entity
public class Place implements Serializable{
    private Integer id; // @Id
    private String name;
    private Organization organization; // @ManyToOne relation

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

**Profile entity**

```
@Entity
public class Profile implements Serializable{
    private String username;// @Id
    private Set<VisitedPlace> visitedPlaces; // @OneToMany(mappedBy = "profile")
    // Getters and Setters
}
```

**VisitedPlace entity**

```
@Entity
public class VisitedPlace implements Serializable{
    private Integer id; // @Id
    private Date visitedDate;
    private Place place; // @ManyToOne relation
    private Profile profile; // @ManyToOne relation

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

Which will create these tables, but i will show it with sample data too

**Organization table**

```
 ===================== 
| id |      name      |
-----+----------------+
| 1  | Organization 1 |
 =====================
```

**Place table**

```
 ================================= 
| id |   name   | organization_id |
-----+----------+-----------------+
| 1  | Place 1  |        1        |
-----+----------+-----------------+
| 2  | Place 2  |        1        |
-----+----------+-----------------+
| 3  | Place 3  |        1        |
 =================================
```

**Profile table**

```
 ============= 
|  username   |
--------------
| 111@xxx.com |
--------------
| 222@xxx.com |
 =============
```

**Visitedplace table**

```
 ================================================ 
| id | visiteddate | place_id | profile_username |
-----+-------------+----------+---------------- -+
| 1  | 2017-01-01  |     1    |   111@xxx.com    |
-----+-------------+----------+------------------+
| 2  | 2017-02-01  |     2    |   111@xxx.com    |
-----+-------------+----------+------------------+
| 3  | 2017-01-15  |     1    |   111@xxx.com    |
 ================================================
```

My question is how to map next native SQL query to JPQL

> ```
> SELECT p.username, count(distinct pl.id) 
> FROM profile p 
> LEFT OUTER JOIN visitedplace vp
> ON p.username = vp.profile_username
> LEFT JOIN place place
> ON vp.place_id = pl.id AND pl.organization_id = 1
> GROUP BY p.username;
> ```

So i will get next result

```
 ===================== 
|  username   | count |
 -------------+-------
| 111@xxx.com |   2   |
 -------------+-------
| 222@xxx.com |   0   |
 =====================
```

**I have been try next JPQL**

> ```
> SELECT profile.username, COUNT( DISTINCT place.id )
> FROM Profile profile
> LEFT OUTER JOIN profile.visitedPlaces visitedPlace
> LEFT JOIN visitedPlace.place place
> WHERE place.organization.id = 1
> GROUP BY profile.username
> ```

but it do return

```
 ===================== 
|  username   | count |
 -------------+-------
| 111@xxx.com |   2   |
 =====================
```

**So my real problem is in converting next line to JPQL**

> LEFT JOIN place place **ON** vp.place_id = pl.id **AND** pl.organization_id = 1

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, adding **ON** clause is only supported in JPA 2.1 spec.

So till now we can't use **AND** with **ON** clause.

You can get JPA 2.1 specification from http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html

So lets hope we will get it in next release.